# Animation with Autolayout

Tags: animation, ios7, autolayout, uitoolbar

I don't use IB. I am laying everything out with code.

I have a UIToolbar on top of a view. 
I am setting its height to 64 or something and the width obviously to stretch horizontally to fit screen width. 
When I first launch the app, everything is perfect. I change the orientation, toolbar resizes, all good.

Now comes the animation part.

When I swipe up on the view, the toolbar should move up on top of the screen and hide. 
When I swipe down on the view, the toolbar should come back down.

I tried setting the constraints in the following manner.

Initially this.

```
// for width
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[toolbar]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDict]];
// for height
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[toolbar(toolbarHeight)]" options:0 metrics:metricDict views:viewDict]];
```

Now, during Swipe Up

```
[self.view removeConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.toolBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.toolBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

But it is breaking the constraint that is supposed to bring it back down and staying up.

Needless to say, it is driving me mad. Any solutions?

EDIT:

On closer analysis, the "removeConstraint" wasn't working as expected. Basically, it wasn't removing the constraint I wanted it to remove. `self.view.constraints` is an NSArray. Now I need to find a simple way to remove the exact constraint I want.

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to create your heigh constraint using the long form for creating a single constraint. And then assign it to a property. 
Then all you have to do is change the constant value. 
So swipe up would set the height constraint constant to zero. Swipe down would change the height constraint constant to desired height.

You don't need to add and remove that constraint every time.

Comment: No, I want to watch the toolbar being moved up, animation.